# Why is mean square error actually "squared" where just a 'abs' or modulus function gets the work done?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, mean-square-error

Cost function could be also made positive by lots of other methods, simplest being `abs(x)` or modulus function, or just `x^4`, which is computationally expensive. Why only square?

Comment: it's not just about the absolute value, it is also about punishing bigger errors more than smaller errors

Comment: You should also mention differentiability, probably the most important requirement.

Comment: mean "square" error is squared by definition. It's the commonly used error because of statistics theory. In particular when considering the Normal (Gaussian) distribution the probability of events falling within variance multiples is well defined. It's not the only possible error definition however, your alternatives are good as well, but not suitable for normally distributed events.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147001/is-minimizing-squared-error-equivalent-to-minimizing-absolute-error-why-squared

Comment: As I understand it, historically "absolute value" was considered intellectually abhorrent as it has no derivative and cannot be used in symbolic reasoning of the calculus - squaring *does* have a derivative and, by convention, the square roots are positive and conveniently also have a derivative. This led to things like "Root Mean Squared Error", or RMSE, rather than simply using the average absolute value of error as a fit statistic.

Answer (score 2):

It is not always "only square". E.g. [quantile regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression) uses `abs(error)`, Huber loss combines L1 and L2 loss, and there are other options (e.g. relative or logarithmic errors). But `error^2` has some advantages:

- `error^2` gives the most intuitive solution, because `sum(x-a)`
  where `x` is a vector and `a` is variable parameter is
  minimized by `a=mean(x)`, and mean is a very meaningful statistic.
- this solution, `mean(x)`, is much easier to find computationally, than, e.g. `median(x)` (minimizer of `sum(abs(error))`, or a minimizer of `sum(error^4)`. This is especially important when we do a regression - that is, estimate not just mean of `y` but mean of `y` conditional of `x`, which may be a complicated function.
- `error^2` cares most about large errors, which is sometimes what you want - the larger an error is, the more you care about it.
- `sum(error^2)` is a transformation of [likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) if errors are assumed to be normal - and normal errors are both frequent in many applications and well supported by statistical theory. If you minimize sum of squared errors, you maximize likelihood.